# SQL Server CONTAINS ignores single quote before asterix

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Let's say I have table NamesTable, which has text index on Name column

```
DECLARE @String2 NVARCHAR(20) = '"SomeName''*"'
SELECT * FROM NamesTable
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, @String2)
```

What does single quote in CONTAINS string mean? Why is it ignored?

Comment: Looks like it's all symbols, in general, which are ignored.

Comment: What were you expecting to find? The string you are searching for is `SomeName'*` which I would expect to simply become `SomeName`. This is because `'` separates the `*` from the word and does not become a wildcard such as `SomeName*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CONTAINS` is used for full-text searching, and can search for:

- for a word or phrase
- the prefix of a word or phrase
- a word near another word
- a word inflectionally generated from another word, such as spoon and spooning
- synonyms

Perhaps you should use:

```
DECLARE @String2 NVARCHAR(20) = '"SomeName''%"';
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.NamesTable NT
WHERE NT.Name LIKE @String2;
```